# Android onClick does not change the text color of buttons

Tags: android, xml, button, onclick, onclicklistener

I am trying to change the color of the text on the buttons. Here is my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class ColorPatternGameActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
protected Button button1; 
protected Button button2;
protected Button button3;
protected Button button4;
protected TextView test;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
    Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b4);
    TextView test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    button4.setOnClickListener(this);

    test.setText("testing");

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == button1) {
        test.setText("Red");
        button1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    else if (v == button2) {
        button2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        test.setText("Green");
    }
    else if (v == button3) {
        button3.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        test.setText("Blue");
    }
    else if (v == button4) {
        button4.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        test.setText("Yellow");
    }
}   
}
```

Clicking on the buttons does not change the text or the color. I have implemented onClick before and it has worked fine which has me all the more confused as to why it isn't working.

If it helps a sample of my xml where I declare a button is:

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/b1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:text="1"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assigning **local variables** with the result of `findViewById`.  Since you're testing reference equality in your `onClick` method with the member variables, that will always be false.

Change (and the others too):

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
```

To:

```
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
```

Although, it would probably be cleaner if you just had different click methods for each button.

Comment: Facepalm, its always something simple never the big stuff. Thank you wsanville.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating buttons pro-grammatically or not, this solution will work.

just use casted object ((Button) v).setTextColor(Color.GRAY);  as below:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast toast;
    Log.w("ANDROID DYNAMIC VIEWS:", "View Id: " + v.getId());
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case MY_BUTTON:
        toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked on " + v.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25, 400);
        toast.show();

        ((Button) v).setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);


        break;
        // More buttons go here (if any) ...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize class variables like

```
protected Button button1; 
protected Button button2;
protected Button button3;
protected Button button4;
```

then in `onCreate` method you are again initializing your buttons

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b4);
```

Which make the buttons local to onCreate method, this should not be done, in your case the class variables have not been assigned anything to do, so your code doesn't work...

I suspect this won't happen if you had set onClickListener's inside onCreate itself, as it would be local to your method the text color would have been changed...

So instead of using `Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);`in onCreate use `button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);`

If you are using Eclipse IDE, then button1 will be of blue color indicating that it is a class variable...

Answer (score 0):

You can see this example

```
 <Button android:id="@+id/testing"
         android:text="Testing"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#000000">
```

---

Here Button text color can be Black  Now I am change it to White color on Button Click

```
 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      if (v == testing) {
        testing.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
         }
     }
```